# RConsole keyboard shortcuts in Windows

Tags: r, keyboard, shortcut

I'm a long-time user of R on a Mac but have started at a company where I get to use R in Windows. I've managed to get R installed by admin however once installed, everything seems to work okay except the keyboard shortcuts.

For instance:

- I cannot hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd> to copy.
- I can't scroll to the next or previous word with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> or <kbd>R</kbd>
- I cannot use my mouse to move to a location on screen
- I cannot hold delete a line from where my cursor is by hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>
- I cannot undo with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>. Instead, it tries to quit R when i do this.

I've tried Googling the problem and browsing the forums. Is there are a basic issue I'm missing? I've checked with a colleague of mine who had installed first as a test and nor does his version support the keyboard shortcuts.

Would installing RStudio help with this?

My version: R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25) on Windows 7

Comment: I don't use keyboard combinations much, but RStudio helps with a whole lot of things.  Btw, try Ctrl-C to copy and Ctrl-V to paste.

Comment: Hi Matthew, have tried copying and pasting within it as well. Cannot do it either as I can't select within R in the first instance (by Keyboard or mouse). With pasting, can paste stuff outside of R into it but that's it.

Comment: Are there people out there who still use "raw" R routinely? :) I suggest you go for an IDE and stick with it (RStudio, ESS, Eclipse+StatET plugin, among others).

Comment: R for Windows doesn't have a lot of these kind of features. You might find the [R for Windows FAQs on CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#Windows-Features) helpful.

Comment: Same problem: sometimes R quit my .Rnw file when I try to undo (with shortcut CTRL + Z or in the Edit menu). Sometimes it works fine!